# how to determine an event which triggered an inline function with a real parameter in the Firefox?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, parameters, inline

This function is declared inline in many tags: `<i onClick="noteFc('someNoteText1')">  ...  <i onClick="noteFc('someNoteText2')"> ...`   calling with different note texts, dependent on a call place.

```
function noteFc(str){
  var bubble = window.event.srcElement.getElementsByTagName('i')[0];
  diff=...
  bubble.style.left = diff + "px"; 
}
```

My code works in Chrome, but FF says "undefined" `window.event` which I read in the function,
FF `event` object is not visible in function body, thus event should be passed via an explicit parameter of the function, which means for me that all inline declaration(calling?) of function should be rewrited in all source codes to   `onClick=noteFc(event, "someNoteTextN");`   but what with this coding in Chrome, where the event object is conceived differently?
An element's target is sufficient, thus calling can be `onClick=noteFc(this, "someNoteTextN");`   probably works everywhere, but adding is much work too, led to a bulkier, intricate source code.
Sniffing variable `this` in the function `noteFc(str)` led to a blind street, because FF puts `[object Window]` into this global variable, contrary to Chrome value `[mouseEvent]` – is there any way to distinguish between such values? In addition, I not see how can I to mine a clicked element from an entire `[object Window]` in FF.

I have searched the net for many hours, but I found only statements that FF itself passed an event as hidden argument (without parameter declaration in inline, only alone parameter in a definition). Unfortunately all found examples have no real argument passed into.
What in case of passing the explicit real parameter into function? Where is a event implicitly secretly passed into function in such case?
 `arguments[0]` contains `str` (explicit text parameter), and `arguments[1]` is undefined.
Is there any direct way (reading of global variable in function body would be best for simplicity) for determining an event(target is sufficient) which triggered an inline function with a real parameter in the Firefox?

(Way other than jQuery.)

---

Edited: quotes was added due to a reader mention.

Comment: A little unrelated: do you wrap your onclick in quotes? Parser might go crazy when seeing stuff like <i onclick=noteFC("something");>

Comment: precis: `<i onClick="noteFc('someNoteTextN')">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
<i onClick="noteFc(event, 'someNoteText1')">
```

The "event" argument is passed to the event handler compiled from the attribute, but it's then the handler's decision whether to pass it on to the noteFc function it calls or not.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have tried it formerly, but any bug in implementation must have been there, too much trials simultaneously.

Comment: Has it meaning that extracting from any global variable (or from argument hidden in function declarations) is impossible in FF? It means to rewrite entire source codes...

Comment: "Meaning" as in `window.event` being a non-standard IE-ism which WebKit (and hence Chrome) copied?  Or meaning in some other way?

Comment: Offered solution `onClick="noteFc(event, 'someNoteText1')"` has an explicit parameter, passing `event` into function body (where variable `event ` is unaccessible). Is there any possibility for extracting event/target from any global variable (or from argument hidden in function declarations) accessible in function body in FF?

Comment: @user2978791 No, there is no.  Since event dispatch can nest, having a global variable really doesn't work very well.